# How long does it take to receive bitcoins?

Tags: transactions, confirmations, receiving

I bought 1.25 BTC but after 2 days I see nothing. What is wrong?
This is the [transaction](http://blockexplorer.com/a/4CkCXPJxFa).

Also, I went to freebitcoins.appspot.com, since they claim thay they give for free 0.005 bitcoins per visitor. I did everything correct and the site said that I could see the transaction at freebitcoins.appspot.com/recent_sends.

But when I clicked on my transaction, it said: No such transaction

http://blockexplorer.com/tx/1eaf91e7d4ae3a8f976eaa346f4332d8bfd999d209ef899612e5b2995db0eeb9

Please guys tell me what is wrong?

Comment: If you see the transactions in block explorer, you have the Bitcoins. Block explorer is showing you the actual live network data.

Comment: If you know the transaction ID but it doesn't appear in block explorer, it means this is a floating transaction which hasn't been included in a block yet. This transaction already appears in BE at the time I'm writing this. For a list of known floating transactions you can use for example http://bitcoincharts.com/bitcoin/ .

Comment: Also, search on Blockchain.info will show transactions that have not yet made it into a block.

Answer (score 5):

You should check the following:

1. Are you sure you entered the right address to receive the Bitcoins?

   - If the address is not correct, the coins are lost
2. Did your Bitcoin client download all the blocks in the chain? (>150000)

   - If not, you need to let it run for awhile, until it downloads all the blocks, making sure that you have a couple connections and the block number is slowly increasing in your client application

Answer (score 1):

Did you allow ample time after downloading the bitcoin app to allow the entire block chain to be downloaded from within the app? If not, then the most recent transaction wont be visible to you.