# Why I haven't received my transfer from BTCGuild?

Tags: transactions, confirmations, receiving

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How long does it take to receive bitcoins?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/2064/how-long-does-it-take-to-receive-bitcoins)

At BTCGuild site it shows on Payout History:

2012-01-26 19:01:06 1BiNp9GmFJv1VuoudsJy8Ke79qvh6BPDzp  0.20000000
2012-01-22 07:29:27 1BiNp9GmFJv1VuoudsJy8Ke79qvh6BPDzp  0.11390889
2012-01-20 01:36:25 1BiNp9GmFJv1VuoudsJy8Ke79qvh6BPDzp  0.23492573

But in Bitcoin software, I haven't received the first (0.20000000) payout.

Only the second and the third were received.

Why have I got this problem?

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Blockexplorer](http://blockexplorer.com/address/1BiNp9GmFJv1VuoudsJy8Ke79qvh6BPDzp), you should see all of those transactions when you reach block 163971. Your client probably needs to finish synchronising with the network, as the first transaction is the newest one. If you see the second transaction, then you still have about 7 days at most to synchronise. Just leave your client on for a couple hours and you should see your last 0.2 Bitcoins arrive.